# Why does this code continue to loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, cycle

I have a simple jquery-script, embedded into my html code, it uses a plugin written for jquery, called cycle. When I try to use the code, it works, but it keeps looping for some reason. This means that I'm trying to create a simple slideshow, but when I click either "next" or "previous" it does what it should, but after that it continues to scroll the pictures without clicking. Why is this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slide').cycle({
fx: 'scrollHorz',
speed:  'slow',
next:   '#righta',
prev:   '#lefta',
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you add your `HTML`?

Comment: does the plugin, by default, have a cycle interval? Check the plugin API first

Comment: Well, maybe the plugin is not coded to do that?

Comment: I just googled the docs - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23 - it has options for `pager` and things by the looks

Comment: I would love to add the html code, but I cant even figure out how to post it, so it appears decently, with line breaks... how do you do that?

Comment: @user3420063 - Use the     **`**    symbol befor and after ( *next to the full colon on most keyboards* ) - http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plug in then auto scrolling is default behaviour unless you set timeout to 0. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slide').cycle({
fx: 'scrollHorz',
speed:  'slow',
next:   '#righta',
prev:   '#lefta',
timeout: 0
});
</script>
```

Comment: quick and perfect answer. +1

Comment: And as per my comment above!

Comment: Which was written a minute after my answer according to SO =P

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is a slideshow plugin by default which means it will behave as a slide show by default which is what it sounds like the issue is for the op. You need to add the `timeout` param. Setting it to 0 will stop the slideshow from advancing automatically. so try the below:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#slide').cycle({
       fx: 'scrollHorz',
       speed:  'slow',
       next:   '#righta',
       prev:   '#lefta',
       timeout: 0
     });
   </script>
```

Comment: The timeout: 0 worked, like a charm thanks! Also is anyone familiar with css formatting? I just cannot get the pictures in the slideshow to appear in the middle where i want them! I've tried every option, but still they appear the same, as if they are not affected at all.

Comment: Place them in a `DIV` and position the `DIV`